# Why isn't "head -n" working after being piped to two echo commands?

Tags: linux, bash

I ran this command:

```
echo "a"; echo "b" | head -n1
```

And expected this result:

```
<p>a</p>
```

But instead I got this:

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
```

Why didn't I get my expected result? Are there any mistakes in my command?

Comment: `;` separates commands, also chains. If you want to group commands together use `{` `}` or `(` `)`

Answer (score 5):

The order of evaluation of your statement is effectively:

```
echo "a"; (echo "b" | head -n1)
```

So, to override, use:

```
(echo "a"; echo "b") | head -n1
```

That's it...

Comment: You can also use curlies, which I don't think spawns a subshell - `{ echo "a"; echo "b"; } | head -n1`